# Yet another python scoping issue

Tags: python, scoping

I've read bunch of scoping posts but I haven't found answer to mine. I use python 2.7.6.
Here's the code:

```
def play(A, B):
    state = START_STATE
    #player = None
    while state[1] < goal and state[2] < goal:
        if state[0]:
            player = B
        else:
            player = A
         state = resolve_state(state, player(state))
    return player
```

This raises UnboundLocalError. Uncommenting line 3 effects in always returning None variable, yet I am sure that the player variable is always either A or B. Making player a global variable solves the problem. Can anyone explain this behaviour? From what I've read while and if statements don't create their scopes so the function should be the scope for variables declared in while/if block.

Error says: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'player' referenced before assignment"

I am sure that the loop executes because START_STATE = (0, 0, 0, 0) + I double checked it with printing + making player global solves the problem and it doesn't affect the loop entrance conditions

@jonathan -> it stayed from older version

Comment: I've never seen syntax like line 2 before. Also, have you tried using pdb and stepping through your code?

Comment: *yet I am sure that the player variable is always either A or B* - How are you sure?

Comment: Can you give us the error as well? It will help to specify where the issue is

Comment: Show the full traceback. *What* raises UnboundLocalError and where?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it seems perfectly valid syntax although it is rather strange; it unpacks the `START_STATE` list into four separate variables, and then re-packs them into `state`. No idea why OP wants to do that though.

Comment: Most likely the while loop is never being entered and the error is on the return of a variable that doesn't exist. Don't be "sure" of something until you've *proven* it. You are your own worst enemy.

Comment: loop is executed I am sure of that

Comment: @konradko : your code is definitly _not_ entering the loop - cf the code sample in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is *not* going through the loop - here's a simplified code that demonstrate it:

```
# noloop.py

def loop(A, B, x):
    #player = None
    while x:
        if True:
            player = B
        else:
            player = A
        x = False

    return player
```

and the calls and results:

```
>>> import noloop
>>> noloop.loop("A", "B", True)
'B'
>>> noloop.loop("A", "B", False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "noloop.py", line 12, in loop
    return player
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'player' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

So your assertions are wrong, point cleared. Note that your code relies on two global variables, `START_STATE` and `goal`, which makes debugging harder. First rewrite your function to get rid of all globals (hint : pass `START_STATE` and `goal` as arguments), then add some debugging code (like a few print statements before, within and after the loop), and you'll probably find out by yourself what went wrong.

Comment: bruno thanks for your explanations. I once again checked the loop and the problem was that START_STATE was list, therefore first iteration was just fine, but the other function calls used modified START_STATE variable. now i understand what I've made wrong. Lessons learned.